# Books for exercises on tensors and multilinear algebra (including scalar product spaces)

Tags: reference-request, tensors

I'm self-studying tensors from a book that doesn't have exercises. To get a better feel for index manipulation, tensor results and calculations, I'm looking for a book that has many exercises in these topics. I've looked at other tensor-related reference request questions but to my knowledge exercises wasn't a focus in any of them, so apologies if another question exists with the same intent.

I'd be grateful if those knowledgeable in the subject can point me to such books. The end use case is to get comfortable enough with tensor and index machinery that I can easily do calculations in Physics (e.g. special/general relativity, etc.)

---

For more context, I've covered: vectors, covectors, basic linalg results, linear transformations, matrix representations of transformations/vectors/covectors, change of basis, tensors, basis/components of tensor spaces, sums/direct sums, subspace annihilator, pullback of covectors/covariant tensors by a linear transformation, ordinary and metric contraction of tensors, bilinear functions, inner product space, adjoints, orthonormal bases, linear isometries, perp, time cones, Lorentz vector spaces, flat/sharp maps and index raising/lowering (for vectors/covectors only so far).

Comment: Since you specifically mention index manipulations, I might recommend Pavel Grinfeld's *Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces*.